# Как создать множество из чисел типа int?

Tags: python, множества, преобразование, set

```py
a = input() + input()
# На вход подаются данные 123456 и 23456
```

Как преобразовать их в множество чтобы получилось?

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...}` а не `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'...}`

Comment: Я переоткрыл вопрос, чтобы вы могли добавить свой вариант ответом. Но это так себе способ.

Comment: @insolor так вроде, же, попытка ответа в самом вопросе - так себе решение

Comment: @Dmitry "так себе ответ" - тоже ответ. В любом случае ответ должен быть в ответах, а не в вопросе.

Comment: @insolor я это и имел в виду, что ответ должен быть в ответе. Если он решает задачу, но мне не нравится по ряду причин - это другое, не относящееся к первому моему тезису. Косноязычен немного

Comment: @Dmitry вопрос был закрыт как дубликат -> автор добавил свой вариант решения в сам вопрос (потому что нельзя добавить ответ к закрытому вопросу), потом еще добавил [дублирущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1413598/1365) -> я переоткрыл вопрос, чтобы автор мог добавить ответ нормально

Comment: ТС, перенесите ваше решение в ответ, нажав `Ответить на собственный вопрос`

Comment: Готово. Вопрос решён. Задание отредактировано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если цифры вводятся слитно, и каждая цифра (отдельный символ числа) должна стать отдельным элементом списка, то делайте так:

```
a = input() + input()
b = set(map(int, a))
print(b)
```

Или через set comprehension:

```
a = input() + input()
b = {int(x) for x in a}
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
a = set(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: Почти, но не совсем. Ваш код возвращал {1234567}(целое число),  а надо {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...}.
У меня получилось решить другим путём.

`a, empty = list(input()) + list(input()), set()`
`empty.update(int(i) for i in a)`

Comment: В примере в вопросе цифры подряд идут без пробелов, split не нужен, достаточно просто `a = set(map(int, input() + input()))`

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** переделал под множества, не сразу увидел=(

Можно сразу прописать приведение типа, хоть для одного, хоть для многих стандартных вводов

```py
int_input = int(input())
```

Лучше в цикл обратить вашу конструкцию

```py
a = set()
for i in range(5):
    a.add(int(input()))
```

Либо принимать строку сразу и работать с ней, без многого числа input

```py
a_str = input() # 1 2 3 4 5
a_int = {int(i) for i in a_str.split()}
```

Comment: Этот код не подходит для решения.

Comment: @DaniilZhernosek почему?

Comment: над получить `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...}`  из 123456, а с этим кодом получаем `{123456}`

Comment: @DaniilZhernosek читайте внимательнее, код работает

Comment: @DaniilZhernosek вы изменили вопрос, в котором указали, что последовательности подаются слитно, уже после того как дан был ответ. У меня нет дара провидения

Comment: пример того, какими должны быть выходные данные - был изначально.  Читайте внимательнее.

Answer (score 0):

функция input возвращает тип str, преобразуйте её в int

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ.

```
a, empty = list(input()) + list(input()), set()
empty.update(int(i) for i in a)
```